# How to fix strange layout produced by masonry plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I am using the masonry script to create a panel of images on my website. I have three different sizes for the images, 33%, 50% and 66% so everything should fit together nicely, but I'm getting this:

[image]

The first row is fine but the second row should be the 'celebrity four weddings' photo and then ideally the blue 'alan titchmarsh' photo, not the 'this morning' photo.  I am already using the imagesLoaded extension so it is arranging the images after they are loaded. Was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this?

My html:

```
<div class="masonry">
      <div class="masonry-sizer"></div>
      <div class="masonry-item masonry-item--width3"><img src="images/press/masonry/1.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item"><img src="images/press/masonry/2.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item masonry-item--width2"><img src="images/press/masonry/3.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item masonry-item--width2"><img src="images/press/masonry/4.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item masonry-item--width3"><img src="images/press/masonry/5.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item"><img src="images/press/masonry/6.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item"><img src="images/press/masonry/7.png" /></div>
      <div class="masonry-item"><img src="images/press/masonry/8.png" /></div>
</div>

<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $grid = $('.masonry').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    columnWidth: '.masonry-sizer',
    percentPosition: true,
    horizontalOrder: true,
    initLayout: false
  });

  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
  });
</script>
```

My SCSS:

```
.masonry:after {
content: '';
display:block;
clear: both;
}

.masonry-item, .masonry-sizer {
width: 33.333%;
float: left;
img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    }
}

.masonry-item--width2 { width: 50%; }
.masonry-item--width3 { width: 66.666%; }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code itself, the problem could be from the images and their size. You can test this by removing the images and putting random text. If the layout works, the problem is with the images

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu I gave it a shot but it still gives the same layout without any images inside the divs like this: https://i.imgur.com/PJShCp5.png

Comment: hmm I copied your html and css in a codepen and put some text instead of images, and it looks just fine.

Comment: are your .masonry-item--width3 and .masonry-item--width2 overwriting the initial css correctly?

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu Yeah, they both overwrite the widths without issue =/ Could it be something to do with .masonry-sizer? Not exactly sure how it relates to the items

Comment: Try removing that and try again, let's see what happens. It truly is unrelated there

Comment: Looks like the masonry breaks completely if that's removed or its style is removed. When you put the code into a codepen did you include the masonry javascript files? I just tried it and without the masonry script it actually tiles correctly, but that's because the heights of the masonry-items were all the same having only text inside

Comment: please try using the same picture in all the divs, if it breaks even worse, it's because of the images

Comment: Just gave it a shot, it's still giving me the same layout

Comment: I reproduced it on my localhost and it still works fine:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Oy2Agd7

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu Got it all working now - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed! For anyone who might have the same issue:

The masonry-sizer (or grid-sizer by default) class has to be a number that fits into all other masonry-items without a remainder. So using 33.33% here doesn't work with a masonry-item size of 50%. I changed the masonry-sizer to 25% and then all masonry-items are 25%, 50%, or 75% etc.